# Contact 7 form fields are not working in safari

Tags: wordpress

I am using contact 7 form for my contact page..it is working fine in every browsers except safari.In safari couldn't submit the form.In safari Not even able to give input values to the fields.How to fix this?
Thank you

safari console:
[image]

firefox console:
[image]

screenshot of admin area:
[image]

```html
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f72-p151-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form action="/contact/#wpcf7-f72-p151-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-12 dose-contact-form row" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="72">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.1.1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f72-p151-o1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="151">
<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-field col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required input-text" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your Name"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-field col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email input-text" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your E-mail"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-field col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required input-text" id="text" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your Title"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-field col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="2" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea form textarea" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Message"></textarea></span>
</div>
<div class="contact-btn form-field align-center">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit submit-btn" id="submit"><span class="ajax-loader"></span>
</div>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div>
```

this is the form code from inspect element..

Comment: share some screenshot or code

Comment: i have added the screenshot of the form from admin area.No errors are showing up but couldn't type anything to the input values

Comment: Ok let me check.

Comment: @beginner Does Safari report any errors? Are there any errors in WordPress debug.log?

Comment: no errors are showing up..on form submission validation errors are coming because i set the fields as required

Comment: @VasimShaikh I tried deactivating other plugins but no change..

Comment: @Mulli have some errors in console I have attached the screenshot to the question...

Comment: @beginner Good start. I dont remember seeing such errors (especially 409) but first you have to clear the *red* errors. I guess it will solve your problem

Comment: @Mulli..i have rectified those red errors..still the form is not working

Comment: can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue.

user-select:none;

was applied in my css.Simply changing that made everything work fine